# Access remote SQL Server - using Windows Authentication - from IIS Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication, remote-access, remote-server

I have been asked to connect .NET web services to a remote SQL Server, the SQL Server is using Windows Authentication.

I understand how to create the connection string for SQL Authentication but I do not know how I can achieve this using Windows Authentication.

There needs to be some sort of authentication to allow the remote process to run, but from what I have read, when using WA you don't specify a Username/Password. So how does the calling process get validated to allow access to the remote SQL Server.

Am I correct in saying that WA is used for access on the same Domain/Server, but for remote access SQL Authentication should be used?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that Windows Authentication works well when both server and client are on a single domain or in a trust relationship, but it is possible to pass authentication through a connection string, with the user name in terms of 'DOMAIN/User' for access.

Whether or not to use SQL Authentication vs windows is largely a question of where the relevant servers are located and how you wish to distribute administrative burden.

Comment: When using 'Domain/User' access for WA, would a connection string take the following form...? connectionString="Data Source=ip_address\username;Database=databaseName;Integrated Security=True;"

Comment: www.connectionstrings.com is a fantastic resource, but typically I think it will be in the form of 'Server=SQL_server;Database=MyDB;user=DOMAIN/User;password=pass;Integrated Security=false'

Comment: The whole idea is NOT to provide the username in the connection string. The webserver must pass the credentials of the user it's serving on to SQL Server.